# Где найти туториалы/уроки по GTK#?

Tags: c#, книги, gtk

Гуглил про GTK, GTK#, GTK C# перекидывает в основном только на официальный сайт, где есть простой пример кода и все. 
По JavaFX нашел кучу видео и материала, а по GTK# никак не могу. Там же непонятно как вообще интерфейс строить, как запускать это все и пр.

Comment: Связанный: [Книги по C# и другая литература](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/416584/%d0%9a%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b3%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d0%be-c-%d0%b8-%d0%b4%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b3%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%83%d1%80%d0%b0)

Comment: [GTK# tutorial](http://zetcode.com/gui/gtksharp/) и [Руководство GTK# для начинающих](https://www.opennet.ru/docs/RUS/gtk_mono/)

Comment: Вот еще [ссылочка](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/gui/gtksharp/tutorials/) Еще рекомендую присмотреться к [Eto.Form](https://github.com/picoe/eto) или к [Avalonia](https://github.com/AvaloniaUI/Avalonia)